# Deploying app on Docker with Tomcat and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, docker, networking, docker-compose

I have an testApp.war which I'd like to **deploy on Tomcat through docker** (docker is on 10.0.2.157). My testApp will work properly only with **postgres DB** and specified user testUser and password testUserPasswd. I built such a structure:

```
.
├── db
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── pg_hba.conf
│   └── postgresql.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
└── web
    ├── context.xml
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── software
    │   └── testApp.war
    └── tomcat-users.xml
```

Content of all these files are attached below. I start my containers with command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

However when I go to Tomcat on webbrowser (http://10.0.2.157:8282/manager/html) and try to start my testApp I got:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /testApp/
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.20

**What I'm doing wrong? Could you help me with this?**

---

db/Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:9.5
MAINTAINER riwaniak

ENV POSTGRES_USER testUser
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD testUserPasswd
ENV POSTGRES_DB testUser

ADD pg_hba.conf /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/
ADD postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/
```

db/pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all
```

db/postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

web/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
<!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
-->
</Context>
```

web/Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.20-jre8
MAINTAINER riwaniak

COPY ./software /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

web/tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>

  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,admin-gui,manager-gui"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

and finally docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    testApp:
        build: ./web
        volumes:
          - /path/to/tomcat/folder/web/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
          - /path/to/tomcat/folder/web/context.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/HelpdeskApp/META-INF/context.xml
          - /path/to/tomcat/folder/web/context.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml
          - /path/to/tomcat/folder/web/context.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
        ports:
          - "8282:8080"
        links:
          - testAppdb
        networks:
          - testAppnet

    testAppdb:
        build: ./db
        ports:
          - "5555:5432"
        volumes:
          - /srv/docker/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
          - /path/to/tomcat/folder/db/postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
          - /path/to/tomcat/folder/db/pg_hba.conf:/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
        command: postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
        networks:
          - testAppnet

networks:
    testAppnet:
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

Comment: What does `docker-compose logs` show when the issue occurs. Can you check if the war is getting expanded properly and loaded without any issues?

Comment: I check "docker logs CONTAINER_ID" and logs from tomcat container shows:

2017-09-21 14:22:56.952 ERROR --- [ost-startStop-1] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connection error:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

So Tomcat tries to connect to localhost. How can I configure it to indicate to 10.0.2.157?

Comment: You should be connecting to `testAppdb:5432` and not `127.0.0.1:5432`

Comment: Where can I specify that? Where should I change that?

Comment: You would have specified that somewhere in the config `testApp.war`, so you need a new war with db connections details changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OK, I got the solution!**

Thanks *@Tarun Lalwani* for supporting and suggestion.

I had wrong application.yml configuration in Tomcat container. Docker mapped ip addresses of my containers but I shouldn't write just "10.0.2.157" but **name of containers**. So in my example I've got smth like below:

```
(...)
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:postgresql://10.0.2.157:5432/helpdesk_dev
(...)
```

However **right solution was to map name of postgres container** (testAppdb), so correct conf is:

```
(...)
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:postgresql://testAppdb:5432/test_dev
(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I also had the same issue and I could resolve it through your answer. In my case, I have put a wrong ip as the postgresql server ip. Even the server log did not show any error.